# Combining two ffmpeg commands into one in android studio

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg

I want to combine two ffmpeg commands into one.

**Command 1:** Adding GIF and Scrolling Text to Video

```
new String[]{"-ss", "0", "-t", "15", "-i", "input.mp4", "-ignore_loop", "0", "-i", "overlay.gif", "-filter_complex", "[1:v][0:v]scale2ref[b][a];[a][b]overlay=0:main_h-overlay_h:shortest=1,drawtext=fontfile=/system/fonts/DroidSans-Bold.ttf:text='Hello World':fontcolor=#ffffff@1.0:fontsize=(h*w/20000):y=(h/20):x=w-t*200", "-vcodec", "mpeg4", "-preset", "ultrafast", "-codec:a", "copy", "output.mp4"};
```

> OR

```
new String[]{"-ss", "0", "-t", "15", "-i", "input.mp4", "-ignore_loop", "0", "-i", "overlay.gif", "-filter_complex", "[1:v][0:v]scale2ref[b][a];[a][b]overlay=0:main_h-overlay_h:shortest=1", "-vcodec", "mpeg4", "-preset", "ultrafast", "-codec:a", "copy", "output.mp4"};
```

**Command 2:** Remove Current Audio and Add Another

```
new String[]{"-i", "output.mp4", "-i", "audio.mp3", "-c:v", "copy", "-c:a", "aac", "-map", "0:v:0", "-map", "1:a:0" "output_new.mp4"};
```

*Note: Output from 1st Command is Input for Second Command*

Comment: Cross-posted from [Super User](https://superuser.com/q/1690042/356789).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.